# How to change placeholder with Font-Awesome content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-awesome

I want to change the placeholder attribute trying `attr()` using it this way:

```
$(this).attr("placeholder", "&#xf0a4; Mandatory field");
```

But the result is not the Font-Awesome icon , it literally looks looks like this:

```
"&#xf0a4; Mandatory field"
```

Nevertheless, if I put

```
<input type="text" class="mandatory_field form-control" id="affiliation" placeholder="&#xf0a4; Mandatory field"/>
```

with CSS

```
.mandatory_field {  
   font-family: FontAwesome,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
}
```

It works, but I need to know how to get those results dynamically with jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery probably transforming the string to make it safe, try without jQuery `$(this)[0].setAttribute('placeholder', '&#xf0a4; Mandatory field')` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks GillesC, but I obtained:
Uncaught TypeError: [0].setAttribute is not a function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This solution needs only:

- one line of jQuery
- CSS property `font-family:FontAwesome`
- **No HTML at all**

You'll need the specific CSS code for the icon prefixed with a `\u`. Font-Awesome documents only class and unicode. Fortunately, this [site](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/) has what you need. Here's what it should be in jQuery:

> ```
> $('.mandatory_field').attr('placeholder', '\uf0a4 Mandatory field');
> ```

The only difference between CSS and JavaScript font entities is the `u` in the second character position for JavaScript.

In the demo, I also added some styles with the [`::placeholder`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/) pseudo element as a bonus. You can style your placeholders without affecting the user input style.

### Demo

```js
$('.mandatory_field').attr('placeholder', '\uf0a4 Mandatory field');
```

```css
/* With the exception of font-family:FontAwesome everything
|| is optional.
*/

input {
  font: inherit
}

.mandatory_field::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: red;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.mandatory_field::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: red;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.mandatory_field:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: red;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<input type="text" class="mandatory_field form-control" id="affiliation">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `data` attribute to store the awesome font symbol you want and use it combined with the text `$input.data('placeholder') + ' Mandatory field'`.

Code example:

```js
var $input = $('#affiliation'),
    placeholder =  $input.data('placeholder') + ' Mandatory field';
    
$input.attr('placeholder', placeholder);
```

```css
.mandatory_field {  
  font-family: FontAwesome,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-placeholder="&#xf0a4;" class="mandatory_field form-control" id="affiliation">
```